# Python csv reader-zipping reader with range

Tags: python, csv, iterator

I am having a really simple csv file of this type (i have put the Fibonacci numbers for example):

```
nn,number
1,1
2,1
3,2
4,3
5,5
6,8
7,13
8,21
9,34
10,55
11,89
12,144
13,233
14,377
15,610
16,987
17,1597
18,2584
19,4181
20,6765
21,10946
22,17711
23,28657
24,46368
25,75025
26,121393
27,196418
```

and i am just trying to bulk process the rows in the following manner (the fib numbers are irrelevant)

```
import csv
b=0
s=1
i=1
itera=0
maximum=10000
bulk_save=10
csv_file='really_simple.csv'
fo = open(csv_file)
reader = csv.reader(fo)
##Skipping headers
_headers=reader.next()

while (s>0) and itera<maximum:
    print 'processing...'
    b+=1
    tobesaved=[]
    for row,i in zip(reader,range(1,bulk_save+1)): 
        itera+=1
        tobesaved.append(row)
        print itera,row[0]    
    s=len(tobesaved)        
    print 'chunk no '+str(b)+' processed '+str(s)+' rows'  
print 'Exit.'
```

The output i get is a bit weird (as if the reader is omitting an entry at the end of the loop)

```
processing...
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10
chunk no 1 commited 10 rows
processing...
11 12
12 13
13 14
14 15
15 16
16 17
17 18
18 19
19 20
20 21
chunk no 2 commited 10 rows
processing...
21 23
22 24
23 25
24 26
25 27
chunk no 3 commited 5 rows
processing...
chunk no 4 commited 0 rows
Exit.
```

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?
My guess is the zip function.

The reason i have the code like that (getting chunks of data )is that i need to save in bulk  csv entries to sqlite3 database (using executemany and commit at the end of every zip loop, so that I will not overload my memory.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
import csv

def process(rows, chunk_no):
    for no, data in rows:
        print no, data
    print 'chunk no {} process {} rows'.format(chunk_no, len(rows))

csv_file='really_simple.csv'
with open(csv_file) as fo:
    reader = csv.reader(fo)
    _headers = reader.next()

    chunk_no = 1
    tobesaved = []
    for row in reader:
        tobesaved.append(row)
        if len(tobesaved) == 10:
            process(tobesaved, chunk_no)
            chunk_no += 1
            tobesaved = []
    if tobesaved:
        process(tobesaved, chunk_no)
```

prints

```
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 5
6 8
7 13
8 21
9 34
10 55
chunk no 1 process 10 rows
11 89
12 144
13 233
14 377
15 610
16 987
17 1597
18 2584
19 4181
20 6765
chunk no 2 process 10 rows
21 10946
22 17711
23 28657
24 46368
25 75025
26 121393
27 196418
chunk no 3 process 7 rows
```

Comment: This is a really good solution.
I am just wondering why there is this weird behaviour on the reader...